# Pool de Aplicativos - Tamanho da Fila (queueLength)

Tags: iis-7

Tenho me deparado com um comportamento estranho do IIS 7.

Existem 4 aplicativos publicados no IIS e cada um deles tem uma pool específica.

Pesquisando na web, encontrei diversas páginas (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd441171(v=office.13).aspx) orientando a configuração desse campo utilizando uma especie de fórmula: **quantidade de usuários simultâneos x 1,5 = tamanho da fila**.

Até aí tudo bem!

O problema é que possuo 2 aplicativos que tem a pool configurada com o valor 7000 para o tamanho da fila  e constantemente o erro 503 é apresentado para o usuário.

Seguindo o raciocínio da fórmula com o que apliquei na configuração (7000 / 1,5) é como se eu tivesse 4666 usuários simultâneos e na verdade esse sistema não possui mais de 10 usuário, quanto mais simultâneos.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar causando esse consumo excessivo de solicitações?
Obrigado!